# Weird keyboard behavior re: holding keys down

Tags: keyboard

On Big Sur 11.4. My keyboard has started behaving very strangely, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have looked through other topics about how to toggle accented characters on/off and those suggestions haven't worked. This seems to have happened out of the blue -- not with any update or new software installation or restart.

1. My keyboard was set up such that when I hold down a letter key, such as e, a little menu would pop up that would allow me to select an accented version of that letter, if one exists (like è). But if held down a key that doesn't offer accents, like, say, the delete key, there would be a slight delay but then it would be as if it's pressing that key over and over again quickly (so, by simply holding down the delete key, I could eventually delete a whole line of text). This has always been standard operation for my keyboard.
2. Suddenly, I seem to have lost the ability to add accents to characters. So, for example, holding down e just acts like I was holding down a non-accentable key. So, holding down e eventually gives me eeeeeeee. No accent menu.
3. I read that in order to turn accents on, I need to go into the keyboard menu in settings and switch the "Key Repeat" slider all the way to off. I did this, and it did not restore my ability to get accented letters by holding down the key. It also removed the "key repeat" functionality from keys like delete, which is useful.

I just want to go back to my original keyboard functionality as described in 1) above.. how do I do it??

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134941/how-to-stop-a-key-on-my-macbook-air-keyboard-showing-the-character-accent-menu

Comment: Does this happen in all apps? Have you tried in TextEdit for example?